# Как принудительно завершить поток?

Tags: c++

С помощью `async` запускаю в `main` поток, в котором крутится бесконечный цикл. Как завершить этот поток?

Comment: добавить фалг выхода из бесконечного цикла.

Comment: Цикл на то и не имеет условия выхода, потому что он должен быть бесконечным.

Comment: Варианты: 1. добавить всётаки флаг. Обнулять извне. 2. Делать потоку terminate. 3. Завершить процесс через terminate - тогда завершится всё.

Comment: terminate тоже не лучший способ, утечка ресурсом вможет быть.

Comment: Никак не завершить. А любая попытка прервать / прибить его оставит приложение в несогласованном стостоянии.

Comment: Ну если не хочет автор вопроса делать нормально через флаг - пусть делает хоть как-нибудь. Мне до сих пор не попадались такие потоки которые нельзя прерывать. Если поток делает "чисто" вычисления - то его можно прерывать. это как вариант. Само лучше - добавить в цикл флаг.

Comment: Скорее автору надо определится, что он хочет - иметь бесконечный цикл или иметь возможность завершать его. Это взаимоисключающие варианты.

Comment: А что за `assign` ? Объясните пожалуйста. Не знаю такого в c++

Comment: @vegorov по-моему вы ошиблись вопросом. Тут нету таких слов.

Comment: @nick_n_a `С помощью assign запускаю в main поток`

Comment: Тут всёравно чем запускает.

Comment: Бесконечный цикл, с точки зрения языка С++, является неопределённым поведением. Поэтому добавляйте условие выхода и используйте его.

Comment: @ixSci, звучит как-то очень подозрительно о_О, какой-нить референс можно, что это UB?

Comment: допустил опечатку, не `assign`, а `async`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, [intro.progress](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1.1)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а что Вы делаете в этом бесконечном цикле?

Comment: @vegorov переодически меняю переменную, переданную в него как аргумент

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну тогда да, заведите флаг завершения потока, защитите доступ к нему с помощью, например, `std::mutex`, и заваршайте цикл по флагу. А снаружи после изменения флага делайте `std::join`

Comment: @Fat-Zer [Видео по теме](https://youtu.be/rNNnPrMHsAA?t=8m5s).

Comment: @VTT, спасибо за видео, улыбнуло, но AFAIK компиляторы подобного не делают, если не могут доказать, что все операции внутри цикла «чистые» (в терминологии gcc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*.pro файл для QtCreator:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
LIBS += -lpthread
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

bool ExitFlag = false;
int  someVariable = 0;
std::mutex threadMutex;


void threadFunc(){
    while (true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        someVariable = std::rand() % 100;
        std::cout << "var:" << someVariable << std::endl;
        bool needExit = false;
        threadMutex.lock();
        needExit = ExitFlag;
        threadMutex.unlock();
        if (needExit){
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, threadFunc);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    threadMutex.lock();
    ExitFlag = true;
    threadMutex.unlock();
    f.get();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
var:83
var:86
var:77
var:15
var:93
var:35
var:86
var:92
var:49
var:21
Hello World!
```

Comment: Можно усовершенствовать через atomic, использование mutex затратнее

Comment: @Semerkin верно, затратнее.

Comment: @Semerkin я плохо помню тонкости `std::memory_order`, и вообще не обладаю достаточными знаниями по работе с `std::atomic<T>`, если не лень приведёте пример ?

Comment: решение подходящее, вот только у меня возникли другие проблема: почему-то не могу скомпилировать код. При попытке компиляции выдает ошибку.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch у меня gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04)

Comment: ``std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<int (*())()>, int>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<int (*())()>&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<int (*())()>, int>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<int (*())()>&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
2.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implISt12_Bind_simpleIFPFivEvEEiEC1EOS7_EUlvE_JEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC2IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implISt12_Bind_simpleIFPFivEvEEiEC1EOS7_EUlvE_JEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x69): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch добавьте библиотеку `-lpthread`, gcc использует её в реализации потоков

Comment: а, ясно. Я думал это часть стандартной библиотеки

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я тоже удивился когда в первые попробовал использовать потоки из стандартной библиотеки. Причём в Visual Studio всё работало само по себе, а вот дома в gcc под Linux понадобилось добавлять pthread

Comment: И в принципе, это примерно то же самое, что `while(!needExit)`.

Comment: С atomic  я не работал, но это несложно) достаточно обозначить переменную атомарной и обращаться как будто это неразделяемый ресурс

Comment: @Semerkin Не всё так просто, как кажется на первый взгляд. [раз](https://habr.com/post/195948/), [два](https://habr.com/post/197520/)

Comment: @vegorov, грабли начинаются при реализации сложных неблокирующих структур... а с простым флагом выхода в 9 из 10 случаев проблем не возникнет даже если объявить его обычным `volatile` и не использовать атомарные операции... а `std::atomic<bool>` в данном случае можно лепить и не думать...

Answer (score 0):

Завершить отпущенный поток извне нельзя, если в вашем потоке нет условия выхода, то это ошибка.
Для винды есть функция TerminateThread https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx, но её использование опасно и чревато

Comment: Ваш ответ фактически не содержит решения. Лишь рекомендации и ссылки. Как кометарий - хороший, как ответ...